# PHP validate a list of constraints

Tags: php, expression, eval

I have an array of `<` and `>` constraints on variable names that I get from the user:

```
$constraints = array('1<x','x<5','y>4');
```

Where `$x` and `$y` are defined in the relevant scope.

I want to verify that *all* the constraints hold (return `true` or `false`)

How can I do this without using `eval` ?

Comment: Why do you need the array? Can't you just do `if (1 < $x && $x = 5 && $y > 4)`?

Comment: Without eval? Write it to a file and include it

Comment: Check them one by one. Split the condition into pieces: the operator and the two operands. You can do it with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) or with [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Identify the operator (`<` or `>`), the variables (`x`, `y`) and the numbers then compare the current values of the variables with the numbers. Write a function that can do such a check for one expression and all the variables you have (I assume you know forehand their names).

Comment: How did such data ended in an array?

Comment: You can't do it with `eval()`, since the variables don't have `$` before them.

Comment: Basically, you need to write a constraint parser. Loop through the array, parse each constraint, and then perform the required test.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this, you'll have to write it yourself. Since the constraints appear to be pretty simple, parsing them should not be very complicated.

Comment: Do what Barmar said and use `explode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Alejandro, one question : do you want to check if **all** constraints return true or **all** constraints return false? I mean, if they all return the same value?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez , if they all return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concocted a partial answer here. It doesn't loop, but it does support the five different comparison operators.

```
function lt($p1, $p2) {
    return ($p1 < $p2);
}
function le($p1, $p2) {
    return ($p1 <= $p2);
}

function gt($p1, $p2) {
    return ($p1 > $p2);
}
function ge($p1, $p2) {
    return ($p1 >= $p2);
}
function eq($p1, $pw) {
    return ($p1 == $p2);
}

function apply_rule($rule, $x, $y) {
    $matches = NULL;
    if (!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(<|>|=|<=|>=)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/', $rule, $matches)) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid rule: " . $rule);
    }
    //var_dump($matches);
    $p1 = $matches[1];
    $operator = $matches[2];
    $p2 = $matches[3];

    // check if first param is a variable
    if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z]+)/', $p1)) {
        $p1 = $$p1;
    }
    // check if second param is a variable
    if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z]+)/', $p2)) {
        $p2 = $$p2;
    }

    switch($operator) {
        case "<":
            return lt($p1, $p2);
        case "<=":
            return le($p1, $p2);
        case ">":
            return gt($p1, $p2);
        case ">=":
            return ge($p1, $p2);
        case "=":
            return eq($p1, $p2);
    }
}

var_dump(apply_rule("x>=10", 10, 20));
```

Comment: This solution is also limited in that you have to supply all of your parameters to the apply_rule function. It could be expanded/altered to receive an array of values.  Or a variable parameter list. The regex to extract variables vs. parameters is also somewhat limited and may not respond under all circumstances. It would be helpful to see some use cases.

Comment: Instead of having a mini function for each case, just put the function contents into the switch where needed. For example for `case "<":` replace `return lt($p1, $p2);` with `return ($p1 < $p2);`

Comment: Yep that looks pretty tidy.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people do know that the `$` symbol in `php` is actually an operator that evaluates the variable.

```
$total_expressions = true;
foreach($constraints as $c) {
  #parse the expression in to the number, and the variable
  $parts = explode(">",str_replace("<",">",$c));
  $i = is_numeric($parts[0]) ? 0 : 1 ;
  $n = $parts[$i];
  $v = $parts[1-$i];
  # At this stage, $v is the variable name, and $n is the number
  # This line is kinda hard coded to only ">" or "<", but you get the idea
  $expression = strpos(">",$c) && $i ? $$v > $n : $$v < $n;
  $total_expressions = $total_expressions && $expression;
  if (!$total_expressions)
      break;
}
```

`$total_expressions` would be true only if all the constraints hold.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know that *all* constraints are valid, you can pass them to a function that does the checking. It can check each constraint one by one using a `foreach` loop. If the current constraint is not valid then it will return `false` and stop checking. Otherwise, if it reaches the end of the loop it will return `true`. The values for the variables are passed into the function as two arrays as used in `str_replace()`.

```
function validate($constraints, $search, $replace) {

    foreach ($constraints as $constraint) {

        // replace variables in string with submitted values
        $constraint = str_replace($search, $replace, $constraint);

        if (strpos($constraint, '<') !== false) {
            // extract parts from less than constraint
            list($a, $b) = explode('<', $constraint, 2);
            if ($a >= $b) {
                // $a is greater than or equal to $b i.e. not less than
                return false;
            }
        } else if (strpos($constraint, '>') !== false) {
            // extract parts from greater than constraint
            list($a, $b) = explode('>', $constraint, 2);
            if ($a <= $b) {
                // $a is less than or equal to $b i.e. not greater than
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // no invalid constraints were found...
    return true;
}
```

You can then use it to check your `$constraints` array,

```
// variables to search for
$search = ['x', 'y'];

// variable replacements
$replace = [5, 2];

// constraints array
$constraints = array('4<x','x<6','y>1');

// run the function
var_dump(validate($constraints, $search, $replace));
```

The function does assume that the data is passed to it exactly as you've described. You may want to add some checks if the data format could vary.

Comment: What about >= and <= and = ?

Comment: The original question says "I have an array of < and > constraints", doesn't mention any others.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, `$x` and `$y` aren't the only variables that can be constrained, so the hard-coded `str_replace` is a problem

Comment: Pretty sure my solution above will also suffer from this problem because the apply_rule function assumes the values to be compared are supplied to that function. If your rules are going to refer to more than x and y, then apply_rule will need to be modified to accept more parameters -- perhaps an array or something.

Comment: @Alejandro Rodriguez Updated so it now accepts any number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to evaluate only simple expressions and you know in advance the number and the names of the variables then you can write a simple parser:

```
/**
 * Parse and evaluate a simple comparison.
 *
 * @param string  $condition e.g. 'x<4'
 * @param integer $x         the value of 'x'
 * @param integer $y         the value of 'y'
 */
function compare($condition, $x, $y)
{
    // Verify that the condition uses the format accepted by this function
    // Also extract the pieces in $m
    $m = array();
    if (! preg_match('/^(x|y|\d+)([<>])(x|y|\d+)$/', $condition, $m)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot parse the condition");
    }

    // $m[0] is the entire string that matched the expression
    // $m[1] and $m[3] are the operands (the first and the third groups)
    // $m[2] is the operator (the second group in the regex)

    // Replace the variables with their values in $m[1] and $m[3]
    foreach (array(1, 3) as $i) {
        switch ($m[$i]) {
        case 'x':
            $m[$i] = $x;
            break;
        case 'y':
            $m[$i] = $y;
            break;
        default:
            $m[$i] = (int)$m[$i];
            break;
        }
    }

    // Compare the values, return a boolean
    return ($m[2] == '<') ? ($m[1] < $m[3]) : ($m[1] > $m[3]);
}

// A simple test
$x = 7;
$y = 3;
echo('$x='.$x."\n");
echo('$y='.$y."\n");

echo('1<x: '.(compare('1<x', $x, $y) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE')."\n");
echo('x<5: '.(compare('x<5', $x, $y) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE')."\n");
echo('y>4: '.(compare('y>4', $x, $y) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE')."\n");
```

The code works with integer values. To make it work with floating point values just replace `(int)` with `(double)` on the `default` branch of the `switch` statement.

The regular expression:

```
^               # match the beginning of the string
(               # start capturing group #1
  x               # match the 'x' character 
  |y              # ... OR (|) the 'y' character
  |\d+            # ... OR (|) a sequence of 1 or more (+) digits (\d)
)               # end capturing group #1     <-- find the captured value in $m[1]
(               # start capturing group #2
  [               # match any character from the range
    <>              # match '<' or '>'
  ]               # end range
)               # end capturing group #2     <-- find the captured value in $m[2]
(x|y|\d+)       # the capturing group #3, identical to group #1
$               # match the end of the string
```

With simple changes the code above can be adjusted to also allow `<=`, `>=`, `=` (change the regex) or a list of variables that is not known in advance (pass the variables in an array indexed by their names, use `$m[$i]` to find the value in the array).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, `$x` and `$y` aren't the only variables that can be constrained